# Use of 'would have' to refer to What was very likely in the past

Tags: usage, modal-verbs

We can use 'would' to refer to 'what is very likely. We use it to show probability.
These are some examples that I took from some dictionaries:
He would be a teacher.

The guy on the phone had a Southern accent." "That would be Tom."

I think my swimming pool would [=could] hold 20,000 gallons of water.

**So my question is can we use 'would have' to refer to those things which we think was very likely in the past**?

As generally we use 'would have'in conditionals to talk about something that did not happen in the past.

Comment: Yes. If you wanted to buy a Rolls-Royce 10 hp car in 1904, it would have cost you £395.

Comment: When you say _we use 'would have' in conditionals to talk about something that did not happen in the past_ do you mean the non-standard and, to many people, wrong, US usage in place of the past perfect (e.g. 'I wish you would have told me you were a vegetarian'?

Comment: Which would have got you about 200,000 pounds of tea if purchased retail in 16 ounce quantities, or probably close to a million pounds of tea if purchased wholesale by the shipload.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey I meant the main clause of the type 3 conditionals. Not that use with 'wish' where they replace it with 'had'

Comment: Yes. _Since all schoolboys learned Latin in those days, it would have been easy for him to understand the inscription_.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey I still not get it. I was listening to India's foreign minister and in his speech he said " Many of you would have watched that movie". He didnt mean any conditional with it like the example you gave me. He was trying to say  that many of his audiences may have watched that movie. And then he went on to perhaps recite a dialogue from that movie. So what I wanted to ask that can we use 'would have' to refer to something that we believe was true without having any condition implicit or explicit.

Comment: I find the Foreign Minister's phrasing odd, and think that he possibly should have said 'many of you **will have** watched that movie'. He is talking about a surmise that he thinks is very likely to be accurate.

Comment: @KateBunting Thankyou. I still have some doubts remaining. For example I saw someone crossing a road then I Said to myself that  'He would be 40yrs old'.(using would to refer to what is very likely). Now at the same time I remembered another guy who crossed the same road at the same time just a day before and then making a logical guess Can I say to myself about his age "He would have been 30yrs old judging from the way he looked"

Comment: @MichaelHarvey But I have read some usage of 'would' where it is used to make a sentence sound polite by using it in place of 'will'. So can it be also true for the FM's choice of words?

Comment: *Many of you **would** have watched that movie* is just another way of saying *Many of you **will** have watched that movie*. OR plain *Many of you [**have**] watched that movie*, where the only reason for *optionally* including ***have*** is that Present Perfect implies "relevance to time of utterance". And there obviously ***is*** relevance, since the speaker goes on to deliver some "quotes" from the movie, in the expectation that at least *some* of his audience will recognize those quotes. You don't *need* to include modal ***would*** in such contexts, so don't think about it too much.

Comment: @FumbleFingers  "He would have been 30 years old, judging from the way he looked. (The speaker is guessing the age based on the appearance of the person.)
She would have been a doctor, according to her resume. (The speaker is estimating the profession based on her resume.)" My question is can 'would have' be used like this without any conditionals mentioned or hidden. Just for the purpose of past speculation and for showing the probability of things in past which I believe to be true.

Comment: *Many of you **would** have...* is often [just a less common](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Many+of+you+would+have%2CMany+of+you+will+have&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) (read, "more affected") version of *Many of you **will** have...* - which as previously pointed out, is an unnecessarily complex alternative to *Many of you [have] verbed*.  Don't spend too much time on it. You *never* "need" to use ***would*** like this.

Answer (score 1):

> It would have been a 'roo you encountered, not a yeti. Yetis are rare in Australia.

The past likeliness can be relative to an unlikeliness.